# How to use the two stage simulated annealing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, simulated-annealing

I've been reading the following paper 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/293043297_A_two-stage_algorithm_for_combinatorial_testing

I'm failing to understand how exactly the first stage develops. I understand
that the author is using the Best Extended algorithm, but I'm not sure
how each method is being developed, like the 
initialize-last-column and compute-missing-tuples. Also, it looks like
I'm also not sure if I should already know the value for N. I hope someone
can enlighten me on the subject. My final task is to translate this into a 
c# example.

Comment: Email the author, perhaps?